# First function not working: Device 1 is not termcap

Tags: org-mode

```
(defun next-upper-heading ()
       (interactive)
       (outline-up-heading)
       (org-forward-heading-same-level)
    )
```

When calling, I get the error: how can i research, what is going on here?
Device 1 is not a termcap terminal device

Comment: Both functions need an argument: the number of leverls to go up (or forward). Use 1 for both. With that, your function works for me: no error. How are you calling it and where are you calling it?

Comment: Worked, love you!